# An absolute value eigenvalue question

Tags: spectral-radius

Denote by $\circ$ the Kronecker product, let $|\cdot|$ denote the matrix/vector of absolute values, and let $e$ be the vector of all ones. Comparison is entrywise, i.e., $y \ge x$ is equivalent to $y_i \ge x_i$ for all $I$.

Problem 1: Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix, $n>1$, and assume
$$
(A \circ A)e = (n-1)e.
$$ Then there exists $x \neq 0$ with $|Ax| \ge |x|$.

A weaker formulation (Problem 2):
Assume 
$$
|Ae| = n e.
$$
Then there exists $x \neq 0$ with $|Ax| \ge |x|$.

The first problem is sharp in the sense that assuming $(A \circ A)e = (n-1)e$, then there exists no $x \neq 0$ with $|Ax| > |x|$.

Equality, i.e., there exists $x \ne 0$ with $|Ax| \ge |x|$, is true for the matrix with zero on, $+1$ above and $-1$ below the diagonal, i.e. for $A=(a_{ij})$ with
$$ 
a_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
+1 & i<j\\
0  & i=j\\
-1 & i>j\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: as you stated it, $e$ would be a solution to Problem 2, right?